# How can I fix iCloud folder permission as permanent?

Tags: macos, flutter, homebrew, icloud

Iam working on project using flutter sdk. I have moved my flutter project folder into somewhere else on my Mac. All my files are connected to the iCloud Drive which needs to update the location. I fixed this error as temporary but if i restart my mac this permission will be removed.

flutter run
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone X in debug mode...
                                                                                                       ├─Assembling Flutter resources...                           2.3s                                      └─Compiling, linking and signing...                         3.4s                                     Xcode build done.                                            8.2s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    /Users/zuhairhallak/Documents/development/open311_s/open311_s/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runn
    er.app: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed
    Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone X.

Zuhairs-MacBook-Pro:open311_s zuhairhallak$ xattr -rc .
Zuhairs-MacBook-Pro:open311_s zuhairhallak$ xattr -rc open311_s/

Set back the the folder into right area so I could run it

xattr -rc open311_s/
xattr -rc .

Whenever, i write flutter run. I should not get any errors from Xcode build.

In the Xcode 10.2, I keep getting this error.

error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/zuhairhallak/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dybydwkrsvnntieosjctbmgxdchh/SwiftMigration/Runner/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework':
1) Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Users/zuhairhallak/Documents/development/open311_s/open311_s/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework' to '/Users/zuhairhallak/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dybydwkrsvnntieosjctbmgxdchh/SwiftMigration/Runner/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework'
2) That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”

Comment: When you develop, you should be using git, pretty much, and exclude the local clone from any cloud sync. But get into the habit of committing often, to a feature branch, and of squashing commits as/when appropriate etc. No cloud drive applications I know of will play nice with source code repositories: they were not meant to. There’s no need for them to even consider that need: nobody who develops code should be doing it without version control, and a remote repository to sync with: and that solves the problem permanently. I suggest smartgit for the GUI: it’s excellent, and makes it simple.

Comment: I have downloaded again the file from GitHub and still getting same error. Flutter and Xcode building same time which causes the error which that's what i have found out from researching.